# Why does the Nernstian cell potential remain ideally constant during charge or discharge of an electrochemical cell?

Tags: electrochemistry, nernst-equation

I was reading a couple of papers by Prof. B E Conway, including his book "Electrochemical Supercapacitors", where he came across this statement that the Nernstian potential of an electrochemical cell remains ideally constant during its charge/discharge.

Can anyone please explain this statement? Please try not to use any analogies with water pumps and stuff. Instead, I would highly appreciate proper chemical and mathematical equations being used wherever necessary.

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Comment: Supercapacitor is a different thing than a simple cell https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/aenm.202003311

Comment: Mithoron: The Wiley article you suggested  does not even mention the word Nernst! The OP is reading a book and the book can talk about the Nernst equation!

Comment: @Mithoron I know that supercapacitors are different, but the book compared supercapacitors to batteries, where this particular statement was mentioned

Comment: @AChem By the way, what is 'OP'? I saw it in a couple of other places, too.

Comment: @JitinSathishKumar, OP is the original poster.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation), the Nernst equation is given as follows.

$$
E = E^\ominus -\dfrac{\text{R}T}{z\text{F}}\ln{Q_\text{r}}
$$

Notice the dependence of cell potential $E$ on the reaction quotient $Q_\text{r}$. Thus, during charging or discharging, when $Q_\text{r}$ changes, so will the cell potential.

Comment: Nernst equation has nothing to do with AC or DC current.

Comment: @Achem AC current allows for the measurement of cell potential without changing the electrolytic concentrations because the reversal of current also reverses the chemical reactions that occur, preserving the reaction quotient.

Comment: No ananta. I think there is a misconception here. AC current is not used to measure cell potentials. You are confusing cell potential with conductivity measurements. The latter is indeed dependent on high frequency AC for the reasons you suggest above.

Comment: @AChem please find a source to support your statement. Meanwhile, I will do the same.

Comment: Check any university level physical chemistry textbook or Wikipedia. Search the terms conductivity measurements and potentiometry. In potentiometry the "potential" is measured with zero current drawn. Conductivity exclusively uses AC.

Comment: @AChem but the OP has specifically asked for the potential measurement during charging and discharging, not when there is zero current. Although not being an experimental chemist, I may be wrong about the method of measurement, there is no doubt that changing the reaction quotient when charging or discharging changes the cell potential.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149551/discussion-between-ananta-and-achem).

Comment: Of course the cell potential changes while charging/discharging; the bulk cell electrolyte concentrations change and the reaction quotient in the logarithm changes until it reaches the equilibrium constant K, where the cell potential drops until zero.